# SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_PEEK_AT_IDENTITY for Apache Derby Network Server 10.11.1.1

Tags: derby

I have critical bug after upgrade Apache Derby Network Server 10.11.1.1. After restart application, the counter of generated column value increase to 100. My table:

`CREATE TABLE TICKETSNUM (ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1));
INSERT INTO TICKETSNUM VALUES (DEFAULT);`

Get counter value:

`VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_PEEK_AT_IDENTITY('APP', 'TICKETSNUM');`

I don't understand, this is bug or Derby server need more parameters.

Thanks for any solution.

Comment: Kindly read the tag info before adding a tag to your question. This is about an embedded db, not about embedded systems programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking about the 100 value gap, you just opened DERBY-6790 at the Derby site and I answered this question there: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-6790